# Is IPN required to detect cancellation of REST created Subscriptions?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-rest-sdk

I have REST API created Payment Plans and agreements and would like to be able to detect when a user cancel an agreement. My original take on this was that the cancel_url on the [merchant_preferences](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#merchantpreferences-object) object for billing_plan would be used if a users canceled the agreement through the PayPal API, but I am not seeing any callbacks coming in so perhaps this is incorrect?

I have seen plenty on information on IPN processing cancellations and I would love to know if that is the only way to receive a cancellation notification or should I be using another field in the REST API to set this up?

I'm not against using IPN (hey whatever gets the job done!), but it seems to me that the REST API should have its own capabilities for achieving this as well.

Answer (score 1):

Hey this is Avi from PayPal. Refer to this [github issue](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/issues/69#issuecomment-69647946) for information about getting IPN notifications for subscription events.

The REST API does have [webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-webhooks-overview/), and work is in progress to support subscription events for webhooks as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response!   I am I correct in my understanding that the REST api is incomplete and not actually ready for production use? Or is it simple subscriptions that are incomplete?    I do get a response when creating a subscription but it seems to be devoid of any information which would identify the customer, not payer data not even the transaction id which is displayed to the users account.

Comment: Looks like you ran into [this issue](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/155). The REST API is definitely production ready, and there are issues that are being worked on. Please keep reporting these issues and posting comments on the github threads.